# Slideshow with embedded links

Tags: gif, advertising, animate

What I want to do is create an animated GIF(?) that will scroll thru a number of pictures, when you you click on pic1 it takes you to url 1, when you click on pic 2 it takes you to url 2 etc.  I want to post this on Facebook as an ad.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Images -- gif, jpg, png, etc -- can not contain hyperlinks. You'll have to think of another way.

Comment: Hi Alex. Welcome to GDSE. It's not possible  to do that within a GIF since the format doesn't support hyperlinks or interactivity.  However facebook does have something called [Facebook Instant Experiences](https://www.facebook.com/business/learn/facebook-create-ad-canvas-ads/) - which can be used to create interactivity in an ad.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't do that with a gif format. Idk where you will apply it, but the best approach would be code it. You could use bootstrap ccarousel, that's basically a slideshow and you can put links on each image so on click, something happens.

You can read more about it at their documentation : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/

Comment: I put together a little demo here http://bageltime.github.io/slide/slide.html 
It works for the most part but I can't get the prev and next arrows to show consistently.  Anyway that is not the biggest problem.  When I post to FB it just shows an image placeholder with the title of the page.  I need to see the animation. This does not seems like it would be hard but it is  (for me).

Comment: The arrows are showing consistently to me, what do you mean? Anyway, on Facebook you have some solutions. As someone said previously you have Facebook Instant Experiences (https://www.facebook.com/business/learn/facebook-create-ad-canvas-ads/) . Facebook has also now their own carousel post specifically made for promotions and ads, where you can have links on images. But you need have a Facebook page, I don't know if that's the case? There's the link to that importation, where you can understand it better and learn how to do it https://m.facebook.com/business/a/carousel-page-post

Comment: oh well at least I learned some about bootstrap.